# How to allow a mongooses schema Schema.Types.ObjectId to be empty when filling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I've a mongoose schema called Route as the following:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const collection_label = "routes";
const class_label = "Routes";
const schema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    createdOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    attachedSubTasks: [
      { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Subtasks", default: "" },
    ],
  },
  { collection: class_label }
);
```

The fact is that sometime the  field can be an empty array, but when I want to create a Route i get the following error:

```
ValidationError: Routes validation failed: attachedSubTasks: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "[""]" at path "attachedSubTasks"
```

Is there a way to accept the fact that this can be empty?
I tried without default, with default: "" and with default: null

Answer (score 1):

You need to set default as `null` in your schema not `""`

you have also this way to define **attachedSubTasks** in schema:

```
attachedSubTasks: {
  type: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Subtasks"
    }
  ],
  default: []
}
```

Comment: First of all, why are you using a default value in this case? **attachedSubTasks** is an array of **Subtasks _id** it mean if you want to create a document with an empty array for **attachedSubTasks** you can, you don't need to define a default value for it in your schema.

Comment: this is the whole point of my question, because i'm having an error when i do it, when I sent those value to the DB attachedSubTasks is not mandatory.

Comment: When you create a document, do you agree that you only send the **createdOn** field and not the **attachedSubTasks** field when it has no value?

Comment: Keep in mind that I've removed all fields that may display the nature of the project as it is a customer's project which I guess should not be displayed to the public. The default: [], too does not work. Please find my work around solution as answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The **work around** I've found for this problem can be implemented at the backend side. In the following example, I've just check whether the object's key value's length is less than one (1) if true I delete the object's key so that mongoose's schema does not take this into consideration

```
router.post("/", async (c, r) => {
  let receivedData = c.body;
    receivedData["attachedSubTasks"].length < 1? delete receivedData["attachedSubTasks"]: false
    returnedValue = await mongoose.saveOne(Routes, receivedData);
    statRes.status(200, r, returnedValue);
});
```

If someone has a better solution, don't hesitate to let me know.